# WordPress htaccess Admin Panel Prompting For Password on Main

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have the following in the htaccess file in my /wp-admin folder:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Example"
AuthUserFile "/home/username/.htpasswds/public_html/example.com/wp-admin/passwd"
require valid-user
```

For some reason when I load up a wordpress article it prompts for authentication.
The main page is fine, but individual articles prompt for a password.

Comment: you shouldn't use digest passwords for wordpress admin page because all ajax requests rely on access to the admin pages. the wordpress login system should be sufficient

Comment: People recommend using htaccess as an added layer of security. How can I add it to protect wp-admin (or at least wp-login.php) with out affecting the rest of the website?

Comment: perhaps give [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-all-in-one-event-calendar-admin-ajaxphp-htaccess) a try

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.
The reason why it was prompting for a password is because some WordPress plugins require access to admin-ajax.php.

If you add the following on top of the quote above it will allow you to password protect the wp-admin folder.

```
# Allow plugin access to admin-ajax.php around password protection
<Files admin-ajax.php>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Satisfy any
</Files>
```